# one to many realtionship in laravel showing in view

Tags: php, laravel

i am working on laravel phonebook application i want every phonebook to hasOne clients but the clients belongs to many phone books i have a column in my phonebook table called client_id now when i set relations how can i use them in controller and pass it into view as on object and here is some of my code

phonebook controller

```
public function index(){

$phonebooks = Phonebook::all();
$client = Phonebook::find(?dont know if its right place for it?)->client;
return view('admin.phonebooks.index',compact('phonebooks',$phonebooks),compact('client',$client));}
```

phonebook model

```
class Phonebook extends Model{protected $fillable = ['title','description','client_id','calldate','rememberdate'];public function client() {
return $this->hasOne('App\Client','id');}    }
```

phonebook db migration

```
Schema::create('phonebooks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('title');
    $table->longText('description');
    $table->integer('client_id');
    $table->dateTime('calldate');
    $table->dateTime('rememberdate');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and the client db migration

```
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('title');
    $table->longText('description');
    $table->integer('fax');
    $table->text('adrress1');
    $table->integer('telephone1');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and the view that i want to show in it

```
@foreach($phonebooks as $phonebook)
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{$phonebook->id}}</th>
    <th scope="row">{{$phonebook->title}}</th>
    <td><a href="/admin/phonebooks/{{$phonebook->id}}">{{$phonebook->description}}</a></td>
    <td>{{$phonebook->calldate}}</td>
    <td>{{$phonebook->created_at->toFormattedDateString()}}</td>

    <td>{{$client->title}}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
            <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/phonebooks/' . $phonebook->id . '/edit') }}">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">edit</button>
            </a>&nbsp;
            <form action="{{url('admin/phonebooks', [$phonebook->id])}}" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>@endforeach
```

Comment: What's the output you are getting. Are there any errors?

Comment: `$phonebooks = Phonebook::with('client')->all();` ?

Answer (score 1):

you have client property in Phonebook, use it

```
<td>{{$phonebook->client->title}}</td>
```

Comment: when i use it it just shows all the data in client table with no relations and sort it from top to bottom :)

Comment: try change public function client() { return $this->hasOne('App\Client');

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest loading all the clients with eager loading so it will be more efficient, you can read why on the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

You could do this on your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $phonebooks = Phonebook::with('client')->get();
    return view('admin.phonebooks.index',compact('phonebooks',$phonebooks);
}
```

Then in your view you can access the phonebook client thanks to the relationship you have defined doing this:

```
@foreach ($phonebooks as $phonebook) 
    {{ $phonebook->client->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: this will show me the clients in order 1 to 'n' as much client as i have in database and it wont use client id as realtionship so when i have 3 clients it lists them in view but i want every client to show in the related row with the client_id colomn so that i can understand that this phonebook is having this client

Comment: Im sorry not sure I understand what you are trying to say. Your phonebook hasOne client, so with the code I posted the client related to that phonebook will be loaded, what clients do you want to load? If a phonebook has more than 1 client then youshould do that in your model, return $this->hasMany('App\Client','id'); and then you could do foreach($phonebook->clients as client) on your view

Comment: return $this->hasOne('App\Client'); Maybe it's because you are trying to specify 'id' when it's the default so it isnt necessary

Comment: i will git it a try dear @pol sorry i am a little new to laravel and cant express this things very well i will let you know when i try it thanks for Your answer :)